# Print par numbers

Tags: javascript

I want to print some par numbers in a range between (32, 321), but it's not working. I am using this code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UFT-8">
  <title> </title>
</head>
<body>

    <script>
    function pares(x, y) {

    while (x<y){
        if((x%2) === 0){
            console.log(x)
            x++
        }
        else {
            return false
        }
    }
    }
    pares(32, 321);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am receiving 32 only. How can I make it work?

Comment: `return` immediately stops the function. You don’t need it.

Comment: 33 hits `return false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` statement terminates the function as soon it is encountered. You don't need a return statement here.

```
function printEvenNumbers(x, y) {

    while (x < y) {
        if(x %2 === 0){
            console.log(x);
        }
        x++;
    }
 }
```

[Visualize Execution Here](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=function%20printEvenNumbers%28x,%20y%29%20%7B%0A%0A%20%20%20%20while%20%28x%20%3C%20y%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20if%28x%20%252%20%3D%3D%3D%200%29%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log%28x%29%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20x%2B%2B%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%7D%0A%20%0A%20printEvenNumbers%285,19%29&cumulative=false&curInstr=0&heapPrimitives=nevernest&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=js&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)